# Copying Personal Geodatabase (in Access) with relationship classes to ArcSDE for SQL Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, personal-geodatabase, arcfm

How to copy a Personal Geodatabase (in Access) with relationship classes to ArcSDE for SQL Server.

I tried a simple copy paste and imported, but didn't get the relationship classes.

> error: unable to initialize weights in feeder manager.

ArcGIS Server 10.0 (ArcSDE), SQL Server 2008 r2

Comment: You have a tag for ArcFM but make no mention of using that in your question body.  You then mention it in comments on one of the answers.  Please [edit] your question to provide more precise details about what you tried and where you were stuck.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, both Copy and Import will honor any relationships.
per the [ArcGIS documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000051000000):

> Any data dependent on the input is also copied. For example, copying a feature class or table that is part of a relationship class also copies the relationship class. The same applies to a feature class that has feature-linked annotation, domains, subtypes, and indices—all are copied along with the feature class. Copying geometric networks, network datasets, and topologies also copies the participating feature classes.

The error indicates you are copying in a feature class that participates in a geometric network, and that the geometric network includes the **[ArcFM solution](http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/)** object extension.

The question should be *"how to copy a network with the ArcFM extension to a new database?"*

Recommendations:

1. use the ArcFM [Object converter](http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/10.2%20and%2010.2.1/ArcCatalogTools/webframe.html#ArcFM_Solution_Object_Converter.html) to convert everything to Esri Features before copying
2. Go through the process of enabling ArcFM on the target database so that it can house the ArcFM features you are copying into it. Follow the [instructions here](http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/10.2%20and%2010.2.1/ArcCatalogTools/webframe.html#NewGeodatabase.html)

Comment: yes my question is how to copy a geometric network with the ArcFM extension to a new arcsde database?

Comment: initialize weights and feeder trace are working on personal gdb but when trying on converted arcsde gdb it shows error...any suggestion??

Comment: Have you exported the ArcFM properties from the personal GDB and imported them into the sql gdb? That is a key step. Also, review the [ArcFM documentation](http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/10.1/DesktopConfig/Configure_Feeder_Manager.html) on initializing traceweights.

Comment: i created a new arcsde geodatabase and copy paste my PGDB dataset,relationship classes and geomteric network.then i exported arcfm xml file and import into arcsde.but still its not running

Comment: Did you create/upgrade the ArcFM Database and system tables?

Comment: yes i did create upgrade,after so many tries i hv been able to  run initialize weights, but now clicking trace all feeders not update feeder id.any suggestion ???

Comment: Is feederid populated or blank? check connectivity by using the ootb esri trace tools and geometric nwtwoek repair tools to validate the connectivity before running trave a feeder...

Answer (score 0):

After many tries I was able to copy.

Export current personal gdb to XML workspace document and also export ArcFM properties,
then import XML workspace document and ArcFM properties to ArcSDE.

Before running geometric network don't forget to registered as version.

Use right click import/export from the ArcCatalog tree.